# Unable to change the enabled property of a winform button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made this winform static so that only one instance should be maintained throughout (requirement) . In the form load event I have set the enabled property of few button controls to  false. Later I am unable to set it back to true. Whereas I am able to change all the other properties like visible, text etc..

```
 var myCancelList= controlFilter.FilterControls(this,c => c.Name != null &&       c.Name.StartsWith("btnCancel"));
foreach (Control c in myCancelList)
{
   c.Enabled = false;       
}
```

Help appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I'm pretty sure you've got your logic wrong. Can you post the relevant code? How and where are you enabling/disabling these buttons?

Comment: First, I don't think using static form is a good idea, better use `Singleton` instead. Second, your problem doesn't make sense, make sure you didn't disable your buttons right after your enable them (check for conflict code in events is a good place to start with)

Comment: _Later I am unable to set it back to true._ Show us the code that fails and tell us __where__ is is and how it fails!

Comment: yea, you must be wrong! post a small code that generates the scenario you talking about

Comment: Hi thanks all. Intially I set the property to false programatically.But if I do that during the design time it works fine. I have edited, please check.

Comment: Well, that piece of code shows how you __disable__ some Controls. If the list is non-empty this should work. How do you __enable__?

Answer (score 8):

When re-enabling a control also check that any parent controls are enabled. If the parent is disabled then you won't be able to enable the child.